# Placing null at the end of the List

Tags: java, list, collections, null

I have a need to place null objects at the end of the `List`. Here is a sample what I have done for this purpose:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", null, "B"});

    for(String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    System.out.println("==================");

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> nullStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String string : strings) {
        if(string != null) {
            result.add(string);         
        } else {
            nullStrings.add(string);
        }
    }

    result.addAll(nullStrings);

    for(String string : result) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

I am looking forward to a more efficient and intelligent way to do this. Is it possible to swap inside the actual list so that null node get placed at the end, so that I don't need the other two list(nullStrings, result) and extra iteration.

### Update

Sorting will not work for my case. This sample code I made just for testing purpose. Actually I have a different type of Object. Also Sorting will break the position.

Say I have this `null, Obj2, Obj1`, if do anything like sorting it may happens `Obj1, Obj2, null`. But I need `Obj2, Obj1, null`.

Comment: For `"A", null, "B"`, the result must be `"A", "B", null` instead of `"B", "A", null`

Comment: @johnchen902 it must be `"A", "B", null`.

Comment: Sorting does not break the order if all non null elements compare to equal. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: What is your original problem? Perhaps it would help showing the actual object and explain why the position needs to not change

Comment: @c.s. the comparator way which is shown by Fedy2 worked. :-)

Comment: "I have a need to place null objects at the end of the `List.`" <-- why? A list is bounded by nature, so why do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can sort it using [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Here the compare code:

```
@Override 
public int compare(String left, String right) {
 if (left == right) {
   return 0;
 }
 if (left == null) {
   return 1;
 }
 if (right == null) {
   return -1;
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Note that elements that have an equal value according to this `Comparator` won't be re-ordered. From [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Comment: How do you propose to keep the order of the non-null elements?

Comment: I can't. This code I provided is written for testing purpose. In the actual case I have a different object and sorting will break the occurrence.

Comment: @Heuster if all non nulls compare to equal, their order is preserved

Comment: @kiheru not really, is completely incorrect, `Comparator` explictly defines that `0` should only be returned for elements that are equal. If the outcome is correct then this is "lucky" and may be incorrect in future releases.

Comment: @owlstead for a custom comparator you are free to define what is equal. The recommendation is to be carefull when making it inconsistent with `equals()`, but in this case there is no danger.

Comment: @kiheru OK, but where is it *defined* that the order of the original list will be preserved?

Comment: @owlstead http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort." Edited this in + upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Just move non-null elements to the front and fill the rest of the list with null.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    if (strings.get(i) != null){
        strings.set(j, strings.get(i));
        j++;
    }
for (; j < strings.size(); j++)
    strings.set(j, null);
```

---

If you are using `LinkedList` (or something not a `RandomAccess`), you'll need `ListIterator`

```
ListIterator<String> j = strings.listIterator();
for (ListIterator<String> i = strings.listIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String s = i.next();
    if (s != null) {
        j.next();
        j.set(s);
    }
}
while (j.hasNext()) {
    j.next();
    j.set(null);
}
```

Comment: This is of course correct, but calling `get(i)` may be expensive if you are using a `LinkedList` over an `ArrayList`. Additional points for using the original `List` though.

Comment: @owlstead If you are using `LinkedList`, you'll need `ListIterator`.

Comment: +1 for a linear-time solution - with 5 lines of code, being simpler and more efficient than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The general strategy looks fine to me. I would bring the following changes:

- initialize the result list with the appropriate size
- don't use a separate list for nulls. At the end of the iteration, you just need to compare the length of the initial list with the length of the result list to know how many nulls you need to add.

Although making a copy of the list will use more memory, it could well be faster than changing the initial list, because removing elements needs to move all the subsequent elements each time. And sorting is N*log(N), whereas copying elements is O(N).

[EDIT owlstead]

```
public static List<String> moveNullsToEnd(final List<String> strings) {

    final List<String> newStrings = new ArrayList<String>(strings.size());

    for (String string : strings) {
        if (string != null) {
            newStrings.add(string);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, remaining = strings.size() - newStrings.size(); i < remaining; i++) {
        newStrings.add(null);
    }

    return newStrings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code you can use

Remove all the null elements

```
int noOfNull =0 ,i=0;

for(; i< strings.size() ; i++)
{
    if(strings.get(i) == null)
    {
        noOfNull++;
    }
}
strings.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Filling the array with null after the not null elements

```
for(i =strings.size(); i < strings.size()+noOfNull ; i++)
        {
            strings.add(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("BR64");
list.add("SWG620");
list.add("");
list.add("sw0");
list.add("R124");
list.add("R219");
list.add("TaGh20");
list.add("SW6505");
list.add("");
list.add(null);
list.add("SW_6505");
list.add("swd_157");
list.add("localhost");
list.add("qaGh20_241");
list.add("gen");
list.add(null);
list.add("taGh20");
list.add("zen");
list.add("QWG");
list.add("SWG62_");
list.add("SWG620");


Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 != null && o2 != null && o1.length() > 0 && o2.length() > 0) {
            return (Character.toLowerCase(o1.charAt(0)) == Character.toLowerCase(o2.charAt(0)))
                    ? o1.compareTo(o2)
                    : (Character.toLowerCase(o1.charAt(0)) + o1.substring(1))
                            .compareTo((Character.toLowerCase(o2.charAt(0)) + o2.substring(1)));
        } else {
            return (o1 == o2) ? 0 : ((o1 == null || o1 == "") ? 1 : -1);
        }
    }
});
System.out.println(list);
```

Output-: [BR64, gen, localhost, QWG, qaGh20_241, R124, R219, SW6505, SWG620, SWG620, SWG62_, SW_6505, sw0, swd_157, TaGh20, taGh20, zen, , , null, null]

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.