# Placing null at the end of the List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of object like that: [object 1, object 2, null,null,..,null , object 3, null,null]

I try to move object 3 after object 2 without delete "null case", but it's doesn't work. So I would like to iterate my arrayList from right to left and check if the value is not null and then move  Object 3 behind object 2. I precise that I don't know the number of "null case" between object 2 and Object 3

I try to write this:

```
ArrayList<Type> subList = new ArrayList<Type>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    subList = array.get(i);
    for (int j = subList.size(); j >=0 ; j--) {
        if(subList.get(j)!=null) {
            Collections.swap(subList, j, j-1);
        }                       
    }
}
```

edit:

solution 1: that works for my project

```
for(int i=0;i<subList.size();i++)
    if(subList.get(i)!=null) {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
            if (subList.get(j)==null) {
                Collections.swap(subList,i,j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

solution  2 : copy in other arraylist
doesn't work for my project, don't know why

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", null, "B"});
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String string : strings) {
    if(string != null)
        result.add(string);         
}

for (int i = 0, remaining = strings.size() - result.size(); i < remaining; i++) {
    result.add(null);
}
```

Comment: why not just sort the ArrayList?

Comment: In fact I would like to keep all null "case" and put themat the end of the arrayList

Comment: Do just that: Iterate on the list, remove every null element (and remember how many you removed), then re-add N null at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:**

To swap between object with out create any new List , Use Collections.swap() ; Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList subList = new ArrayList();
    subList.add("1");
    subList.add("2");
    subList.add(null);
    subList.add(null);
    subList.add("3");

    for(int i=0;i<subList.size();i++)
        if(subList.get(i)!=null) {
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if (subList.get(j)==null) {
                    Collections.swap(subList,i,j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 1:**

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList subList = new ArrayList();
    subList.add("1");
    subList.add("2");
    subList.add(null);
    subList.add(null);
    subList.add("3");
    subList=leftShift(subList);
}

public static ArrayList leftShift(ArrayList x){
    ArrayList temp=new ArrayList();
    int count=0;
    for(Object t:x){
        if(t!=null)
            temp.add(t);
        else
            count++;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
        temp.add(null);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: The intention was probably to modify the given list, and not to create a new one.

Comment: @Marco13 Check my second update.

Comment: The solutions suggested here so far all have O(nlogn) or even O(n*n). I just upvoted http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762203/3182664 since it seems to be the most concise and efficient solution.

Comment: thanks! it's work with this method :)

Answer (score 0):

solution from top of my head, is not brilliant, but it will allow you to keep order

```
int nullIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (nullIndex==-1 && list.get(i) == null) {
        System.out.println("nullIndex ="+i);
        nullIndex = i;
    } else if (nullIndex >= 0 && list.get(i) != null) {
        System.out.println("swap ="+i+" "+nullIndex);

        list.set(nullIndex, list.get(i));
        list.set(i, null);
        i = nullIndex;
        nullIndex=-1;
    }
}
```

sorry i forgot you are using arraylist, you can do this simpler

```
int counter=0;
while(subList.contains(null)){
    subList.remove(null);
    counter++;
};
while(counter>0){
    subList.add(null);
    counter--;
}
```